# Should division by one get a special case?

Tags: c++, optimization, cpu

If we have a division by one in an inner loop, is it smart to add special case treatment to eliminate the division:

BEFORE:

```
    int collapseFactorDepth...
    for (int i = 0; i < numPixels; i++)
    {
      pDataTarget[i] += pPixelData[i] / collapseFactorDepth;
    }
```

AFTER:

```
  if (collapseFactorDepth != 1)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < numPixels; i++)
    {
      pDataTarget[i] += pPixelData[i] / collapseFactorDepth;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < numPixels; i++)
    {
      pDataTarget[i] += pPixelData[i];
    }
  }
```

Can the compiler reason this by itself? Do modern CPUs contain any means to optimize this?

I am particularly interested if you consider the additional code beneficial in contrast to the performance gain (is there any?).

Background:

- Numpixels is big
- collapseFactorDepth is 90% of the time 1
- Modern CPUs: Intel x86/amd64 architecture
- Please don't consider the wider things. The memory overhead of loading is optimized.
- Let's not sweat that we should probably do this as a double multiplication anyway.

Comment: Just my thought, if the caller want to divide by one, just do it. (I'll probably not check for `0` either)

Comment: That would be a premature optimization. When you optimize for one thing, you are pessimizing for everything else. Far more important is code clarity.

Comment: Just FYI, if you're gonna ask a performance question like this and you know what you're doing, it's usually a good idea to give some background to the performance issue itself. Otherwise you're just gonna get a bunch of (potentially useless) comments and answers telling you to not to optimize at all.

Comment: Double multiplication? No thanks. For maximum speed, this should be a 16bit fixed-point multiplication (SIMD really likes this). As for your real question, division by 1 is slow on current CPUs.

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule, the answer is **No**.  Write clear code first and optimize it later when the profiler tells you have a problem.

The only way to answer whether this particular optimization will help in this particular hotspot is: "measure it and see".

Unless `collapseFactorDepth` is almost *always* 1, or `numPixels` is very large (at least thousands and possibly more), I would not expect the optimization to help (branches are expensive).

You are much more likely to benefit from using SSE or similar SIMD instructions.

Comment: CollapseDepthFactor is almost always 1 (97%) of the time, still I would not want to duplicate the code if it does not lead to a performance benefit.

Comment: NumPixels is usually large 512x512 up to full HD

Comment: Hmm.  If NumPixels is large, your next problem is that you've got to get all that data from memory to the CPU and back; my intuition is that memory bandwidth will probably be the dominant factor - so still no point optimizing.  Note that my intuition about performance has been right about three times in the last 35 years - ***measure***

Comment: The profiler tells me, that this is one of the bottleneck methods for our load code.

Comment: I disagree with your statement entirely, measuring will not help me, because it will only give info on a single sample (my PC).

Comment: Measuring will give you more information than theoretical pontification.  It is obviously best if you can measure on a range representative of your target  platforms - but a single measurement will be more accurate than guess work.

Answer (score 0):

1. Follow @Martin Bonner's advice. Optimize when you need to.
2. When you need to:

---

```
int identity(int pixel)
{
    return pixel;
}

template<int collapseFactorDepth>
int div(int pixel)
{
    return pixel / collapseFactorDepth;
}

struct Div
{
    int collapseFactorDepth_;
    Div(collapseFactorDepth)
        : collapseFactorDepth(collapseFactorDepth_) {}
    int operator()(int pixel)
    {
        return pixel / collapseFactorDepth_;
    }
};

template<typename T>
void fn(int* pDataTarget, T fn)
{    
    for (int i = 0; i < numPixels; i++)
    {
        pDataTarget[i] += fn(pPixelData[i]);
    }
}

void fn(int* pDataTarget)
{
    fn(pDataTarget, identity);
}

template<int collapseFactorDepth>
void fnComp()
{
    fn(pDataTarget, div<collapseFactorDepth>);
}

void fn(int* pDataTarget, int collapseFactorDepth)
{
    fn(pDataTarget, Div(collapseFactorDepth));
}
```

This provides you a convenient default behaviour, a compile-time divide (which *might* be faster than divide-by-int) when possible and a way (passing a `Div`) to specify runtime behaviour.